# (translated) homophone request - luck & chicken

Tags: homophones

Homophone request.

The Year of The Rooster is upon us.

The Chinese love their homophones.

We have “鸡” (toneless pinyin: ji) chicken and “吉” (toneless pinyin: ji) lucky.

I'm trying to see if there are any English homophones that could match this criteria: rooster, chicken, cock [any form of synonym would be okay] & lucky, auspicious, propitious [any form of synonym would be okay].

(close rhymes might work)

Comment: What about *clucky* and *lucky*?

Comment: Could you narrow this question so that there are only one or two alternatives? List questions are not a good fit for Stack Exchange.

Comment: The root of *auspicious* is actually the Latin word *avis* for bird (as in *avian*, *aviary*, etc.). Originally, an *auspex* was someone who told fortunes based on the flight of birds. That's probably not as obvious as you want, though.

Comment: we have an idiom 'lucky duck' ..but ducks aren't chickens.  and it is not one word and a duck is not a chicken.  Just wanted to share we've got a lucky fowl reference.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I understand your concern but genuinely feel that acceptable answers will be quite limited

Comment: haha . .Fowl/Foul is a homophone meaning either 'fowl', a bird, but frequently a bird to eat... and foul which has a number of negative meanings generally meaning offensive.

Answer (score -2):

A rooster could be also be a booster. They rhyme, and the meaning of booster is close to adding a measure of good luck (Google: Propitious = giving a good chance of success).

A booster is a someone who champions a cause or  offers help or encouragement. Literally, to **boost** is to lift up (Give me a **boost**, please), promote (She **boosted** the seedless orange's easy eating), or increase (The **booster** vaccine added years of protection for the children.)

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! We're looking for long answers that provide some [explanation and context](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](//english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: What does a *booster* have to do with *luck*? *Boosting* is conscious; intentional. Luck isn't.

Comment: @DanBron--To boost is to aid the auspiciousness of whatever you are boosting, adding towards its success. To that extent, it helps, as luck helps, even though boosting is intentional.